# Perltex: How to output to a latexfile?

Tags: perl, latex

I want to:

- Read a text file line by line.
- Structure given in mwe.
- Store in an array and sort them by one of its columns.
- Sorted array should appear in a latexfile as normal for perltex.

Far away from this aim, I struggle with the handing over from Perl variables to the latex output.

I had found no analog code in docs and net. Also tag "perltex" is missing here, nevertheless I hope that someone can help.

```perl
     \documentclass[]{scrartcl}
     \usepackage{perltex}
      % content of text file "verfile" in same dir
      % die & Vers\"ohnung & tr. & vers\"ohnen    & in alle R. gehend &     fehlt                 \\
      % die & Vergoldung & tr. & vergolden    & in alle R. gehend &     fehlt                 \\
      % die & Vergeudung & tr. & vergeuden    & in alle R. gehend &          fehlt            \\

      \begin{document}


      \perlnewcommand{\setline}[1]{$line = $_[0]; return ""} %cp perltex doc p.5
      \perlnewcommand{\getline}{$line;}
      \perldo{  
             $verfile = "verfile";
             open (VF,"$verfile") || die "$!";
             while (<VF>) {
                $line = $_; # works: print "$line\n";
             }
             print "after loop: $line\n";
             return "\\setline{$line}";
            }

       \getline

       \end{document}
```

At the moment I expect only one line to see in the output pdf file for the array work lacks. So the problem remains, Why setline doesn't work?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do, but maybe have a look at the `datatool` package? This might be easier than doing this with perl

Comment: Please provide an example of expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can create a table. This sorts the columns of `verfile` according to the content of the first column, and then creates a LaTeX table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{perltex}
\begin{document}
\perlnewcommand{\verfile}[0]{
  open (my $VF, '<', 'verfile') or die "$!";
  my @lines;
  while (my $line = <$VF>) {
      chomp $line;
      my @fields = split /&/, $line;
      push @lines, \@fields;
  }
  close $VF;
  my @sorted = sort {$a->[0] cmp $b->[0]} @lines;
  my $result = '
    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
  ';
  for my $line (@sorted) {
      $result .= (join ' & ', @$line) . "\n";
  }
  $result .= '\end{tabular}
  \end{table}
  ';
  return $result;
} % done

\verfile
\end{document}
```

Compile this file using `perltex --nosafe test.tex`